# How to format Home partition!

Tags: installation, grub2, home-directory

A short time ago I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows.

A lot of things went wrong and I decided to reainstall Ubuntu on the partitions the old Ubuntu was using.

For this installation I created four different partitions: `\`, `\home`, `\boot` and `swap`, I indicated the old ubuntu partition to be the new home partition (maybe I didn't chose to format it).

Now when I turn on the PC, there are two ubuntus in the grub list, one which is functioning well (the latest) and one which is not functioning well (the earlier). I suppose the earlier ubuntu installation is still surviving in the `\home` partition.

Is it possible to format ONLY the home partition while keeping it structure (or format it and reinstall the structure without getting into new chaos)?

## Some images

**Image 1** - This is my partition list

[image: This is my partition list]

**Image 2** - This is what I get when I click "File system"

[image: This is what I get when I click "File system"]

**Image 3** - This is what I get when I click "home". It is different from my current home folder.

[image: This is what I get when I click "home"]

**Image 4** - Inside there is another! "Home folder" which contains the folder Imagination3, the name of my profile on the old installation. It is the home folder of the old installation.

[image: Inside there is another "Home folder"]

**Image 5** - Returning to image 3, the Temitope folder is the home folder of the new installation, i.e. clicking on it bring me to my current home folder. Note that the new home folder is not equal to the partition `\home`. I'm trying to say: clicking on my current home folder doesn't open the media `\home`, but open `\home\temitope`.

[image: Click on "home"]

---

So, what I need is to put an order in this home directory and partition issue, which I suppose implies eliminating the parasitic old installation, which should solve the grub entry issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `gksu nautilus` to get a file browser window with root access, then open /home, and select everything *except* your home directory ( and any other home directories if you have more than one user ) and delete it.  Hold down shift when pressing delete so it doesn't go to the trash bin, and then close the window when done.

You can run `sudo update-grub` to update the boot menu without the removed system.